# ¿Como ubico varios <DIV> de forma horizontal sin que se posicionen de forma vertical?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Las tarjetas se posicionan una abajo de la otra, pero quiero que se pongan una al lado de la otra. Probe con Space-Between, con Space-Evenly, con Justify-Content: Center; pero no lo soluciona. Seguramente el problema está en otra parte del codigo y eso es lo que no encuentro.

Como este bloque hay dos mas pero con poner esto ya se entiende:

```css
.caja {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #eef6fc;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.caja .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 440px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset -5px -5px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset -5px -5px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.caja .card .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: #eef6fc;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>01</h2>
        <h3>Card One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptas, modi!</p>
        <a href="#">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quieres que los div caja salgan uno a lado del otro?

Comment: O los div con id card?

Comment: Si, los div.caja uno al lado del otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te recomendaría quitar el max-width: 100%; y el flex-wrap: wrap; , este ultimo lo que hace es pasarte la card debajo del parámetro cuando ya esta ocupando el máximo del espaciado permitido.

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo  tienes el siguiente código

```
<div class="caja">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>01</h2>
        <h3>Card One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptas, modi!</p>
        <a href="#">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


   <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>01</h2>
        <h3>Card One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptas, modi!</p>
        <a href="#">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>01</h2>
        <h3>Card One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptas, modi!</p>
        <a href="#">Ver más</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





</div>
```

Y quieres que esas 3 o mas card estén una al lado de otra, prueba dándole a la clase .caja un display:inline;

Espero te sirva. creo que es lo que tratabas de decir en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar  `display: inline-block`, para todos los elementos que se encuentren dentro de la clase `.box`

```css
.box * {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>01</h2>

  </div>
  <h3>elemento h3</h3>
  <div>nuevo div</div>
</div>
```